# OSX Mavericks: Restoring osx via recovery utility

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, reinstall, system-recovery

OSX Mavericks.
My OSX is corrupted and the only option appears to be 
1: Reboot into recovery mode (Control+R)
2: Take the option to reinstall OSX.

Q1: Does this leave  all my data and ALL OTHER folders alone
and
ONLY reinstalls the OSX?
or 
does delete any folders eg in the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

My Mac Pro's PCIe SSD actually became unrecoverably corrupted a few days ago and I just went through what you're experiencing.

**Option 1 Recovery Mode:**  boots from the special recovery partition that is established when OS X Mavericks is installed. You can perform basic system diagnostic and fix tasks, such as `Disk Utility.app` (Repair Disk, Repair Permissions, etc), `Terminal.app` (more advanced debugging),  etc. Try Repair Disk and Repair permissions here before trying Option 2.

**Option 2 Reinstall OS X:** As long as you don't decide to wipe the hard disk via `Disk Utility.app` *Erase* or *Partition* completely, your data will be mostly preserved. To my knowledge, reinstalling OS X overwrites essential directories used by OS X, including:

- /Applications
- /Library
- /Network
- /System
- /private
- /sbin
- /usr

but leaves the following alone:

- /Users

**My Advice**: Try Option 2 first. Then, if that fails and you possess a Time Machine backup, *wipe your hard disk completely via `Disk Utility.app`'s Erase tool*, reinstall OS X clean, and then restore from a Time Machine backup or copy files from your Time Machine backup piecemeal.

Hard disk corruption is a nebulous thing. You don't know what blocks are suspect. Completely reformatting to a fresh HFS+ partition is the "cleanest* approach, as long as you can preserve your data.

**How to create a clean Mavericks install USB key**: http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/23/create-os-x-mavericks-install-drive/